# "Читал Андерсена" или "читал сказки Андерсена"?

Tags: стилистика

Пожалуйста, подскажите, очень нужен срочный ответ. Как правильно писать в художественном тексте: "С детства я читал Андерсена..." или все же: "С детства я читал сказки Андерсена". Нужно ли уточнять? Жду помощи! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта возможны. Если вы хотите подчеркнуть, что читали именно сказки, а не письма, например, то так и пишите. Но в детстве вы вряд ли имели дело с перепиской Андерсена, а то, что он сказочник, известно всем. Поэтому, повторю, оба варианта возможны. Первый - менее формальный, второй - более строгий. Вот и вся разница.

Answer (score 0):

"С детства я читал Андерсена..." или все же: "С детства я читал сказки Андерсена". Допустимы оба варианта, ни один из них не является более предпочтительным. Но в первом используется изобразительно - выразительное средство метонимия (Вы ведь не самого АНДЕРСЕНА читали, а читали его произведения). Во втором варианте Вы  уточняете, что знакомились со сказками данного писателя.